# Routing won't work when there is a slash behind

Tags: php, annotations, symfony

My route cannot be found if I add a `/` at the end as you see below.

```
class QuizController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/quiz/{name}")
     */
    public function showAction($name = '') {
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        $html = $templating->render('quiz/show.html.twig', [
            'name' => $name,
            'title' => 'Hello World'
        ]);

        return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

The problem is:

`myurl/quiz/whatever` **works**

`myurl/quiz` **works**

`myurl/quiz/` **doesn't work**

Whenever there is a slash but no value behind, I get the message

> No route found for "GET /"

I'm new to Symfony. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Comment: Depends, do you want the same route to match both trailing and non-trailing slash?

Comment: @DonOmondi yes, so `myurl/quiz/` should work exactly the same as `myurl/quiz`

Comment: @RezaSaadati ok, in that case,I'm writing you a solution now :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `myurl/quiz` indicates the `{name}` parameter is not used, but when you use `myurl/quiz/` it needs the `{name}` parameter to be passed in.

Suggests you add defaults and a name for the route like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("/quiz/{name}")
 *      defaults={"name" = 0},
 *      name="quiz")
 */
```

Then if you use `myurl/quiz/` it will send `myurl/quiz/0`. This is an example

Comment: This is not working for me. It returns `No route found for "GET /quiz/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the ending slash in the route declaration, the route without / will be automatically redirected to the one with the /

```
class QuizController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/quiz/{name}/")
     */
    public function showAction($name = '')
    {
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        $html = $templating->render('quiz/show.html.twig', [
            'name' => $name,
            'title' => 'Hello World'
        ]);

        return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will add a slash after the parameter `name` but not after `quiz`. Basically if there is a slash after `quiz` and there is no parameter for `name`, it should redirect back to `myurl/quiz`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (via phone) After OP comments Below:

put 2 @Route declarations before controller action, one with slash one without

@Route("/quiz/")

### @Route("/quiz/{name}")

Since OP wants the same route controller to handle both trailing slash and non-trailing slash, the solution is the allow Symfony to accept a slash as part of the variable (which is doesn't by default).

Docs Here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

So your route becomes

```
class QuizController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/quiz{name}", name="quiz_name", requirements={"name"=".+"})
     */
    public function showAction($name = '') {
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        $html = $templating->render('quiz/show.html.twig', [
            'name' => $name,
            'title' => 'Hello World'
        ]);

        return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

Please Note: While this answers the OP's question, it's a dangerour practice. For anyone reading this, it might suit the OP for his logic but note that it will also match any route

```
/quiz*
```

So while the OP wants this, it will also match

```
/quiz/name
/quiz/
/quiz
/quiz/name/edit
/quiz/name/delete
```

For OP, a work-around is to include edit, delete routes before this custom one as Symfony matches routes by first match wins basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, when I use `<h1>{{ name }}</h1>` in my template, the output will be `/`. I don't want `/` to be the value of the parameter `name`. What I want is that the page `myurl/quiz` can be accessable with or without `/` at the end. I am not sure but I think this a configuration issue.

Comment: @Reza, unfortunately, its not that simple. You have to understand how a route is matched to a controller action. The default is to match any static string (eg quiz) then use a / as the url divider. For better functionality, most people redirect all trailing / to without, then use / as the divider. As a last resort you can use the solution above.

Comment: The thing is, machines are not inteligent (yet) so while it might sound simple to a human there is no way for it to know you what you want without some help. For your solution, the only way out I see is to duplicate routes (2 routes can match the same controller) will post a solution once I get back on PC.